# jquery how to find and replace a selected option that has a certain value

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to find in a select the selected option that has a certain value and replace it ?

```
<div id="l1col1" class="selects1" ></div>
<div id="l1col2" class="selects1" ><select><option selected>2</option></select></div>
<div id="l1col3" class="selects1" ><select><option selected>1</option></select></div>
```

I will be more clear, in the example above i want to find the select that has the option selected as 1 and replace it with 3 , is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:contains`

```
$('.selects1 :selected:contains("1")').text('3');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/P2jDH/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$("select").each(function() {
    var option = $(this).find("option:selected");
    if (option.text() == "1")
        //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
    $('select').on('change', function () {
       if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() == '1') 
            $(this).find('option:selected').text('3');
    });
```

**Live Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/5zA4A/12/

Happy Coding :)