# Change value of select list with value of another select list jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the value of a select list with the value of another select list

```
<select class="main-filter" id="Test1" name="Test1"><option value="">Select Option</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Need to replace #ReplaceThisText# with value selected from above select box

```
<select id="selectfilter" name="selectfilter" class="form-control main-filter">
                        <option value="">Sort Products</option>
                        <option value="/?id=na&amp;selectfilter=hl&amp;Type=#ReplaceThisText#">Chnage Value</option>

                    </select>
```

I have tried code from this link [Change the Text of a Option with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459073/change-the-text-of-a-option-with-jquery)
 and [jquery how to find and replace a selected option that has a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098305/jquery-how-to-find-and-replace-a-selected-option-that-has-a-certain-value)
but cannot seem to get it to work

My code is

```
$('#Test1').change(function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem("Test1", $(this).val());
        $('.main-filter :selected:contains("#ReplaceThisText#")').val($(this).val());
        location.href = $(this).val();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:contains` will look at the `.text()` value - but your #ReplaceThisText# is not in the `.text()` value - so you'll need to use `.filter()` to find it instead:

Adding some console.logs so you can see what's happening and updated the `.val(newval)` code to make the replacement.

```js
$('#Test1').change(function() {
  var newval = $(this).val();
  console.log("before", $(".main-filter :contains('Change Value')").val())
  var opt = $('.main-filter option').filter(function() {
      return $(this).val().indexOf("#ReplaceThisText#") >= 0;
  });
  console.log("opt length", opt.length);
  opt.each(function() { 
      $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/#ReplaceThisText#/gi, newval));
  });
  console.log("after", $(".main-filter :contains('Change Value')").val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="main-filter" id="Test1" name="Test1">
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<select id="selectfilter" name="selectfilter" class="form-control main-filter">
  <option value="">Sort Products</option>
  <option value="/?id=na&amp;selectfilter=hl&amp;Type=#ReplaceThisText#">Change Value</option>
</select>
```